# Getting date in double format 43318.4847916667 instead of 06-08-2018 11:38:06

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, hssfworkbook

I am writing a java code to generate an excel file using HSSFWorkbook(.xls). I need to write date in one column in  this format 06-08-2018  11:38:06 but it is generating like this 43318.4847916667.
Here is the code snippet i used.
Please help me how can i successfully write

```
Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
Sheet excelSheet = workbook.createSheet();
Row dataRow = excelSheet.createRow(1);;
Cell dataCell = dataRow.createCell(1);;
CellStyle cStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
CreationHelper createHelper = workbook.getCreationHelper();         
cStyle.setDataFormat(createHelper.createDataFormat().getFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
dataCell.setCellValue(new Date());
dataCell.setCellStyle(cStyle);
```

Comment: In my experience, Excel finds out itself if a date or date time was entered and adjusts the formatting itself. Have you tried to format the date and just write the formatted `String` into the cell? The data format you defined is obviously not working. Maybe set the cell style before you write into the cell, worth a try, I think.

Comment: You just missing the `FileOutputStream` (see answer below), but otherwise the date is generated in excel as you asking for it (using the `dateformat` supplied). Are you using a non-microsoft excel (i.e like OpenOffice, LibreOffice, etc?)

Comment: @deHaar, Thank you for the reply  but if i write it down as String, excel will not able recognize it a date format so we cannot do date operations on it.

Comment: *Curious:* If you want a format like `06-08-2018`, with the year last, then why did you give a pattern like `yyyy-MM-dd`, with the year first?

Comment: @Andreas nice observation. I guess it is a copy paste mistake  I corrected it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cannot reproduce the problem.

The following complete example results in an `Excel` workbook having a worksheet and a proper formatted date in cell `B2`.

Code:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;

class CreateExcelDate {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  try (Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(); 
       FileOutputStream fileout = new FileOutputStream("./Excel.xls") ) {

   CellStyle cStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
   CreationHelper createHelper = workbook.getCreationHelper();         
   cStyle.setDataFormat(createHelper.createDataFormat().getFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));

   Sheet excelSheet = workbook.createSheet();
   Row dataRow = excelSheet.createRow(1);;
   Cell dataCell = dataRow.createCell(1);;
   dataCell.setCellValue(new java.util.Date());
   dataCell.setCellStyle(cStyle);

   excelSheet.setColumnWidth(1, 25 * 256);

   workbook.write(fileout);
  }

 }
}
```

Result:

[image]

---

From your comment it turns out that your question does not show the whole. There is a loop for rows and for each row a date shall be created. And that only works up to 42nd row.

Well that problem is well known. `Excel` has a limit for the count of cell styles per workbook. See: [Excel specifications and limits](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3#ID0EBABAAA=Office_2007).

So, if you create a new cell style over and over in the loop, that limit is sometimes reached. However, you do not always have to create new cell styles in the loop. Cell styles are stored at workbook level. Just create any needed cell style once outside the loop. Then apply only the previously created cell styles to the cell within the loop.

The following works for me and creates 1000 proper formatted dates:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;

class CreateExcelDate {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  try (Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(); 
       FileOutputStream fileout = new FileOutputStream("./Excel.xls") ) {

   CellStyle cStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
   CreationHelper createHelper = workbook.getCreationHelper();         
   cStyle.setDataFormat(createHelper.createDataFormat().getFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));

   Sheet excelSheet = workbook.createSheet();

   for (int r = 1; r < 1000; r++) {
    Row dataRow = excelSheet.createRow(r);;
    Cell dataCell = dataRow.createCell(1);;
    dataCell.setCellValue(new java.util.GregorianCalendar(2019, 9, r));
    dataCell.setCellStyle(cStyle);
   }

   excelSheet.setColumnWidth(1, 25 * 256);

   workbook.write(fileout);
  }

 }
}
```

Comment: Hi Axel Richter, thank you for poviding your code snippet. Yes i agreed this is working correctly for only one row. But i looped it for 50 rows and the issue is not producing till 41th row and from 42nd row it is storing date as a number value as mentioned(43318.4847916667). Please give me any suggestions that would be appreiciated.

Comment: @Anam Qureshi: See my supplements.

Answer (score 0):

If you want "06-08-2018 11:38:06" then your dateformat should be "dd-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss". Otherwise you are just missing the `FileOutputStream` which you need to write the workbook to.

```
private static final String FILE_NAME = "./out/MyFirstExcel.xls";

public static void main(String ... args) {
    Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
    Sheet excelSheet = workbook.createSheet();
    Row dataRow = excelSheet.createRow(1);
    Cell dataCell = dataRow.createCell(1);
    CellStyle cStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
    CreationHelper createHelper = workbook.getCreationHelper();
    cStyle.setDataFormat(createHelper.createDataFormat().getFormat("dd-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss"));
    dataCell.setCellValue(new Date());
    dataCell.setCellStyle(cStyle);

    try {
        File file = new File(FILE_NAME);
        if(!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        workbook.write(outputStream);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Anam, has your question been answered? If so please mark this as resolved, by checking the tick. Tx.

Answer (score 0):

Follow below code for printing date in DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM:ss.

```
String fileName = "myExcel.xls";
WritableWorkbook writableWorkbook = null;
response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
writableWorkbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(response.getOutputStream());
WritableSheet excelOutputsheet = writableWorkbook.createSheet("Sheet1", 0);

DateFormat customDateFormatWithTime = new DateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
WritableCellFormat dateFormatWithTime = new 
WritableCellFormat(customDateFormatWithTime);

int row = 0;
int col = 0;
excelOutputsheet.setColumnView(col, 20);
Label lable1 = new Label(col, row, "Date and Time", cellFormat);
excelOutputsheet.addCell(lable1);

row = row + 1;
col = col + 1;
DateTime myDate = new jxl.write.DateTime(col, row, "Value", dateFormatWithTime);
excelOutputsheet.addCell(myDate);
```